# Java: send messages to websocket without creating many threads

Tags: java, websocket

I have a java program where I input about 500 proxies and 500 “tokens.” It will create a new websocket connection using a random proxy for each token for identification. The websocket returns a time in milliseconds (usually around 40000 which is 40 seconds) for how long I should wait before sending a “heartbeat” message to that connection. How could I do this without slowing down or crashing my pc?

Comment: Make it modular and scale it up depending on what you hardware can handle.

Comment: If the heartbeat time is always the same time between websockets, you could just have one scheduled thread that runs every 40 seconds to broadcast the heartbeat message to all clients

Comment: Would a 4-core cpu be able to handle 500 threads?

Comment: Ok I will try that with one thread